# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this issue on my flutter application. It seems failed to load an API request, but when i try on browser it return okay "http://vplay.id/api/series/popular".

**Debug**

```
exception = {_Exception} Exception: Failed to load
message = "Failed to load"
this = {SeriesProvider} 
 _url = "http://vplay.id/api/"
 _loading = false
 _currentPage = 1
 _pages = 1
 _series = {_GrowableList} size = 0
 _seriesStream = {_AsyncStreamController} 
endpoint = "series/popular"
e = {_TypeError} type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'
 _stackTrace = {_StackTrace} 
 _failedAssertion = "is assignable"
 _url = "package:streamapp/src//helpers/parse.dart"
 _line = 31
 _column = 7
 message = "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'"
```

**Series_provider.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../helpers/api.dart';
import '../models/serie_model.dart';
export '../models/serie_model.dart';

class SeriesProvider {
  String _url = Api.url;
  bool _loading = false;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  int _pages = 1;
  List<Serie> _series = List();
  final _seriesStream = StreamController<List<Serie>>();

  Function(List<Serie>) get seriesSink => _seriesStream.sink.add;
  Stream<List<Serie>> get seriesStream => _seriesStream.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _seriesStream?.close();
  }

  Future<List<Serie>> _process(String endpoint) async {
    try {
      final resp = await http.get(_url + endpoint);

      if (resp.statusCode != 200) {
        throw Exception('Failed to load');
      }

      final data = json.decode(resp.body);

      final series = Series.fromJsonList(data);

      return series.items;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
```

**Helpers/parse.dart**

```
static double checkDouble(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      return double.parse(value);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my first time with flutter, and this is interesting since it only me face this issue (this is an app i get from codecanyon marketplace) with fresh installation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
static double checkDouble(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      return double.parse(value);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem seems from the last `return value`. You may need `return value+.0`.

Answer (score 121):

An idea would be to use `num` instead of `int` or `double` in this case.

Comment: thank you for this best solution are you know about difference between int and num or double and num ?

Comment: @Kiax int and double are both inherited from num

Comment: This is an exellent solution! Thanks

Comment: can we trace where is the line of code ? i use https://app.quicktype.io/ and a lot of payload and dunno where is the line ?

Comment: ah alr solve by sentry to know where is the line [ option + g ]

Answer (score 24):

You only need to add .toDouble() function to last returned value.

```
static double checkDouble(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      return double.parse(value);
    } else {
      return value.toDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

***As Gustavo Rodrigues mentioned below, do not use this as a standard solution, this is only a workaround.***

I had a similar issue getting weather data.

I solved by declaring the variable as a `dynamic` instead of `int` type.

Comment: Please, don't EVER use this solution. dynamic throws your type safety out of the window. paulo conde answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62927320/9695154) is spot on. If you are consuming a JSON that you need to marshall to double, just .toDouble at the end.

Answer (score 5):

it worked !

```
double rating;
rating = double.tryParse(value.toString());
```

if not work try this -> use **num**

```
num rating;
rating = double.tryParse(value.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```dart
double? checkDouble(dynamic value) {
  if(value is double) return value;
  if(value is int) return value.toDouble();
  if(value is String) return double.tryParse(value);
  return null;
}
int? checkInt(dynamic value) {
  if(value is int) return value;
  if(value is double) return value.toInt();
  if(value is String) return int.tryParse(value);
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was because I had to represent my number as a double value, not an int value.

Example:

Change 0 to 0.0.

```
double rating = rating??0;
```

to:

```
double rating = rating??0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var coordinatesFromJson = json["coordinates"] as List<dynamic>;
List<double> coordinatesList = [];
(coordinatesFromJson as List<dynamic>).forEach((element) {
  if (element is int)
    coordinatesList.add((element).toDouble());
  else
    coordinatesList.add(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you?

```
double.parse(rating.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize you variables with double.

```
class MyBrick extends StatelessWidget {
 double x;
 double y;
 MyBrick({required this.x, required this.y});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     alignment: Alignment(x, y),
     child: ClipRRect(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
       child: Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         height: 20,
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

***"Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int?'"***

***in Flutter***

if in this Exception get in Weather api model class.

press    **Ctrl + R**

and      all **int?** replese in **var**